# Lack of audio for SIP call propagated from IPv6 network when using coTurn server

Tags: voip, sip, turn, coturn

We are using coTurn server to allow our SIP appliance work reliably between client apps and teleconferences. During our test's we have found that one type of calls is not working at all. But at first let me explain test scenarios:

Client A - IPv6 (priority) + IPv4
Client B, D - IPv4 only
Client C - IPv6 + IPv4 (priority)

1. Call from A to C - everything ok
2. Call from C to A - everything ok
3. Call from A to B or D - no sound transmitted in both ways
4. Call from B or D to A - everything ok

We understand this results as if call is propagated from IPv6 network the answering site has to be accessible via IPv6 to make successful call but when call is propagated from IPv4 network it does not matter which IP address family is on the aswering call (IPv6 or IPv4)

Listening IP and Relaying IP of CoTurn is set to autodiscovery. We have tested also `allocation-default-address-family="keep"` but this didn't changed anything in test results.

We use ABTO VoIP SDK for dot.Net and iOS but I do not see if this will be important matter in this case. CoTurn version is 4.5.1.1

Did anyone had similar issue with mixed IPv6/IPv4 networks? How can we resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance for help.